# Default SSL and ProxyPass redirect to another domains (on another computer) with it's own SSL

Tags: php, apache, ssl, https, proxypass

The question is is it possible to do following on Ubuntu with apache2, ProxyPass and SSL enabled:

1. I have main server, let's say it's domain is `http://domain.com` - working OK
2. I have SSL enabled with certificate for `domain.com` and `www.domain.com` and `https://domain.com` is working OK
3. By default, I have 2 conf files in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` - `000-default` handling the *.80 virtual hosts and `default-ssl` handling the *.443 virtual hosts. In this second file I have specified all certificate files for `domain.com`
4. In `000-default` I have ProxyPass set redirectiong to server handling the domain `subdomain.domain.com` on local computer 192.168.0.100 - working OK
5. I have certificates installed on 192.168.0.100 for `subdomain.domain.com`. If I point my browser to `https://subdomain.domain.com` it gives warning, because it loads the certificate for `domain.com`.

How to make so, that the request for `https://subdomain.domain.com` to be transfered to 192.168.0.100 and load it's files (for `https://subdomain.domain.com`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working code

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName subdomain.domain.com
  ServerAdmin admin@domain.com

  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/subdomain.key
  SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/subdomain.crt
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/server.ca.pem
  SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/ca.pem

  BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

  SSLProxyEngine On
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPass / https://192.168.0.100/
  ProxyPassReverse / https://192.168.0.100/

  php_flag display_errors on
  php_value error_reporting 7
</VirtualHost>
```